# Convex conjugate of l1 norm function with weight

Tags: convex-analysis

The conjugate of $f(x)=\|y\|_1$ is, by definition,
$$ f^*(z) = \sup_y \{y^Tz - \|y\|_1\} $$

Also we can write
$$f(y)=\|y\|_1 = \max_{\|p\|_\infty\leq 1} y^Tp $$

By using this, we can get the conjugate of $f$:
$$ f^*(z) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } \|z\|_\infty \leq 1\\
\infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

---

Am I right? Moreover, if $g(x)=\alpha\|y\|_1$, how to get the conjugate of $g$? Should the dual variable change to $z/\alpha$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're doing good. For the convex conjugate (aka Legendre transform) of an arbitrary norm, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1477721/168758).

Regarding the second part of your question,

**Claim:** Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $\alpha$ be a nonzero real number, $f : X \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ be a function, and $g = \alpha f$. Then $g^*(x) \equiv \alpha f^*(x/\alpha)$.

*Proof.* For any $x \in X$, we have
\begin{equation}
g^*(x) := \sup_{z \in X}\langle x, z\rangle  - g(z) = \sup_{z \in X}\langle x, z\rangle - \alpha f(z) = \alpha \sup_{z \in X}\langle x/\alpha, z\rangle - f(z) =: \alpha f^*(x/\alpha).
\end{equation}

Thus in particular, taking $f = \|.\|_1$, we obtain $(\alpha \|.\|_1)^*(x) = \alpha \|x/\alpha\|^*_1 = \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if }\|x\|_\infty \le \alpha,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$.

For more transformation rules concerning convex conjugates, you may checkout [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1532534/168758). Another useful resource is [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates).

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Could you see my new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545352/smoothness-of-total-variation-norm-with-weight ?

Comment: Am I correct that if $f(x) = -1 \cdot \Vert x \Vert_\infty$, then $f^\ast (  y ) = +\infty$ everywhere?

Comment: Yes, by direct computation.