# Smoothness of total variation norm with weight

Tags: convex-optimization

Let me write total variation norm
$$ \|u\|_{TV} = \max_{z\in Q} \langle z, Du\rangle, $$

where $Q$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$ and $D$ is the corresponding gradient matrix.

I can smooth TV by
$$ \max_{z\in Q} \langle z, Du\rangle - \frac{\mu}{2} \|z\|^2, $$
follwing the paper Yu. Nesterov, *Smooth minimization of non-smooth functions*, Mathematical Programming (2005).

---

I know if $g(x)=\alpha f$, the dual function is $g^*(x)= \alpha f^*(x/\alpha)$. My question is how to smooth $g$?

Comment: What's your $g$ explicitly ? What's the relationship between the TV semi-norm and your $g$ ? I'll need to see what $g$ you're talking about. The "smoothed" TV above is indeed smooth, as a consequence of the Danskin theorem (since $Q$ is compact!). You can't smooth an arbitrary function :) Please, be specific.

Comment: I am sorry for unclear. $f(u)=\| u \|_{TV}$ as I defined. But it is defined in discrete setting. For example, $f(u)=\sum_{i,j} \sqrt{ (\partial_x u_{i,j})^2 + (\partial_y u_{i,j})^2 }$

Comment: I want to refer to 24page in http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/math301/Lectures/Smoothing.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Given $\alpha \ge 0$ (lookup the definition of mixed norms), you have
$$\alpha\|u\|_{TV} = \alpha \|Du\|_{2,1} = \|\alpha D u \|_{2,1}.$$ So, to smooth $g := \alpha \|.\|_{TV}$, simply replace the linear operator $D$ by the scaled version $\alpha D$.

In particular, you don't need convex conjugates, etc.

Comment: Can the $ \text{Prox} $ of that be calculated?

Comment: In closed form ? No. Iteratively ? Yes. The problem would correspond to what is known as (isotropic) TV-denoising. There are many ways to go about it: Chambolle's algorithm, FISTA, etc.

Comment: Why can't it Closed Form be derived? If you vectorize the image the TV Operator (Anisotropic) can be like $ {\left\| D x \right\|}_{1} $. Is there a closed from for that (In the case $ D = I $, there is - Shrinkage, what about $ D $ which is Discrete Gradient Operator)?

Comment: There is simply no reason to expect the possibility of a closed-form formula, not even in the anisotropic case. This is because pixels / voxels of the image are somewhat mixed-up by the penalty. However, in the latter case, you can use the LARS algorithm as suggested in appendix B.2 of http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/mairal10a/mairal10a.pdf, for example.